# "Cannot find build.xml" error building MuPDF with Ant

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, mupdf

I am trying to implement the MuPDF library in my Android project. When I execute `ant debug` it gives me the following error:

```
Buildfile:
C:\Users\Saket\AndroidStudioProjects\muPdf\mupdf\platform\android\viewer\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AndroidStudioProjects\muPdf\mupdf\platform\android\viewer\build.xml:83:
Cannot find
 C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AndroidStudioProjects\muPdf\mupdf\platform\android\viewer\UsersSaketAppDataLocalAndroidsdk\tools\ant\build.xml
imported from
C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AndroidStudioProjects\muPdf\mupdf\platform\android\viewer\build.xml
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you follow steps from [here](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android) properly?

Answer (score 0):

This path is clearly bogus:

> C:\Users\AndroidNewBee\AndroidStudioProjects\muPdf\mupdf\platform\android\viewer\UsersSaketAppDataLocalAndroidsdk\tools\ant\build.xml

ie. the 'UsersSaketAppDataLocalAndroidsdk' part is obviously not going to work.

Check the setting of your ANDROID_HOME environment variable (try `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` from a cmd window), this is likely to be where the bad part is coming from.